# Display message when there is no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, popup

I have a web method and I use jQuery to display a pop up for this. When I click on search button when there is data then it's working fine, but when there is no data I want to display a message "NO Data" in a label, and also the pop must not display when there is no data. I tried this code:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    success: function (result) {

if(result !==null && result.length >0){
strarr = result.d;
var myarr = strarr;
$("#divcontainer").dialog('open');
Drewchart(myarr);
}
else{
$("#<%=Label4.ClientID%>").text('No data found')
$("#tabledata").hide();
$("#divcontainer").dialog('hide');
}
} ,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can the do the entire operation inside ajax `success` function

```
// Rest of the code
success: function (result) {
          if(result !==null && result.length >0){
                strarr = result.d;
                var myarr = strarr;
                 $("#divcontainer").dialog('open');
                 Drewchart(myarr);
           }
         else{
             $("#someDomElement").text('No data found')
           }
        }
```

If you are following the above approach you can remove this part

```
$("#search_data").click(function () {
             $("#divcontainer").dialog('open');
  });
```

since opening of dialog box will be taken care by

```
$('[ID*=search_data]').on('click', function () {
```

Note: Since `id` is unique you can use

```
$("#search_data").on('click',function(){
  // Rest of the code
})
```

Comment: Also, if there could be a JSON string, but with no items, you could convert the `result` and then check it over:

`jResult = JSON.parse(result);  if (result && jResult.length > 0) { ... }`

Comment: @user2181397  when i try this .. this show excpetion on code. exception is occur because of no data where as i dont want this.. check this   https://media.giphy.com/media/26gJznDimxRyV0zi8/giphy.gif

Comment: this show error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when i check console @user2181397

Comment: @SUPER_USER can you please post the response

Comment: @user2181397 when i try your code this display No data found is visible and also table is hide but pop up appear so when i check console there is error

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: no such method 'hide' for dialog widget instance